# $N = \{f\colon \Bbb R \to \Bbb R \mid f(x) = x + b\}$ normal subgroup of $G = \{f\colon\Bbb R \to\Bbb R \mid f(x) = ax + b\}$

Tags: group-theory

$N = \{f\colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} \mid f(x) = x + b;\; b\in \mathbb{R}\}$ is a normal subgroup of $G = \{f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} \mid f(x) = ax + b;\; a,b \in \mathbb{R}, a\neq 0\}$

How to show this? Is it sufficient to show $fN=Nf$? I get $ax^2+axb+bx+b^2=ax^2+axb+bx+b^2$ on both sides.

Comment: The group operation here is composition of functions, not multiplication.

Comment: You mean g(f(x))=f(g(x) for g in G and f in N? If I compute that I don't get the same result on both sides...

Comment: No, $f\circ g = g \circ f$ would mean that $N$ is central, not only normal. I mean $g^{-1}\circ f \circ g \in N$ for $g \in G$ and $f \in N$.

Comment: If I compute that I get x+b/a as result, which obviously is in N... or not? Ehh maybe I should just show that G is abelian and then show that N is a subgroup of G.

Comment: It is in $N$, so you're done. But $G$ is not abelian, so trying to show it were is doomed to fail.

Answer (score 1):

Try defining a map
$$
\varphi\colon G\to\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}
$$
by
$$\varphi(f)=a$$
when $f(x)=ax+b$ and prove it's a group homomorphism (the codomain is a group under multiplication). What's the kernel of $\varphi$?